# IIS django HttpPlatformHandler infinite loading

Tags: django, iis, deployment, wfastcgi, httpplatformhandler

so i tried to do Http Platform Handler but now i am in an infinite loading screen when i visit localhost.

this is my configfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Python310\python.exe"
                  arguments="C:\inetpub\Comsroomform\Home manage.py runserver --port 80"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="c:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="80" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and after a long while of loading this shows up
[image]

i was told to follow this tutorial: https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: wfastcgi is deprecated, so that's no longer the right way to host Python web apps on IIS. You might switch to HttpPlatformHandler https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Time to come back and answer it.

Django uses a different set of command line options, so you need something like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\python.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" arguments=".\mysite\manage.py runserver %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More details and the steps to try out can be found in my blog post.

### Reference

https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/